# Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-tooltip"

Tags: angular6, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, testcase, angular-test

I am pretty new to Karma/jasmine. While writing a test case, i have encountered this error:
Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-tooltip"

html

```
<div class="col-md-12 align-center">
    <img class="some-class" src="{{ someVariable.imgUrl }}" [tooltip]="someText" triggers="" placement="right" 
    #pop="bs-tooltip" (click)="someMethod(param1, param2)">
    <p class="some-class">{{ someVariable.name }}</p>
</div>
```

spec file:

```
import * as fromAuth from './../../../auth/store/auth.reducers';
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from './upcoming-movies.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { SharedModule } from './../../../shared/shared.module';

describe('MyComponent', () => {

    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                StoreModule.forRoot({
                    ...fromAuth.authReducer
                }),
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                ModalModule.forRoot(),
                SharedModule,
            ],
            declarations: [
                MyComponent
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

And this is the error which i am facing

```
Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-tooltip" ("some-class" src="{{ someVariable.imgUrl }}" [tooltip]="someText" triggers="" 
placement="right" [ERROR ->]#pop="bs-tooltip" (click)="someMethod(param1, param2)">
            <p class="dash-slate-text sub-text"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/MyComponent.html@33:134
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:485:22)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24667:1)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34620:1)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34595:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34496:48
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34496:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34384:1
    at Object.then (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:474:33)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/WorkSpace_2/f360-web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34382:1)
```

Maybe I am missing some bootstrap module in imports. Please help me resolve this matter.

Comment: Yes, you most likely need to import the BootstrapModule.

Comment: I included: BrowserModule, platformBrowserDynamic in my imports and now i am facing:  Error: Unexpected value 'function (extraProviders) {' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation. Also, what will be the correct import for bootstrapModule? I did try but i was unsuccessful.

Comment: Yes don't import `BrowserModule`, it is not needed. Go to the module where `MyComponent` is declared (in `declarations` array) and see what `imports` and `declarations` that module has and see if you need one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I imported ModalModule

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

and inside beforeEach(),

```
imports: [ModalModule.forRoot()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because  TooltipModule is not imported.

Import the following:
`import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';`

and inside beforeEach(),

`imports: [TooltipModule.forRoot()]`